# Laravel :Trying to get property of non-object on file input

Tags: php, forms, laravel

Im trying to do a submit a file with a form submission however I continue to get this error:

**Error:**

```
Trying to get property of non-object
at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Trying to get property of non-object', '/Users/plastics1509moore/Desktop/elephant_gin/app/Http/Controllers/AdminController.php', '33', array('request' => object(Request), 'input' => array('_token' => 'y0ExMD4FoH3y1hRX61IOvMW520rn7AEx0UOzrc2R', 'title' => 'lol', 'description' => 'picture of gin one', 'link' => 'www.google.com', 'image' => object(UploadedFile)))) in AdminController.php line 33
```

I have files set to true. Is the issue the request all?

Here is the Controller function:

```
   public function createSlider(Request $request)
{
    $input = Request::all();
    if (Input::hasFile('image')) {
        $imageName = $input->id . '.' .
            $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $request->file('image')->move(
            base_path() . '/public/assets/image/', $imageName
        );

        $input->image = $imageName;

    }
    Sliders::create($input);
    return redirect('/admin');
}
```

**HTML**

```
{!!Form::open(array('url' => 'admin/new_slider', 'files' => true)) !!}
    <div class = "form-group">
        {!!Form::label('title', 'Title:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
        {!!Form::text('title', null, ['class'=> 'input-mini ina tch'])!!}

        {!!Form::label('title', 'Description:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
        {!!Form::text('description', null, ['class'=> 'input-mini '])!!}
    </div>

    <div class = "form-group">
        {!!Form::label('title', 'Link:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
        {!!Form::text('link', null, ['class'=> 'input-mini'])!!}

        {!!Form::label('title', 'Image:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
        {!! Form::file('image', ['id' => 'imgInp', 'class' => 'prev-upload']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class = "form-group">
        {!!Form::submit('Submit', ['class'=> 'btn btn-default'])!!}
    </div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: use `get_class ()` to know if you are using correct class object , Error is not lying It is fact, but how to notice it well there is a number of ways, only you can find.

Comment: Whats the full error message? That should indicate the variable and line number

Comment: Ah yes its line 33, which is try to get the input's id...but because it hasn't been made it doesn't have an id. I suppose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get the `id` from the input. Your form isn't passing any `id` so naturally, your input won't have the `id`.

You can create the slider first and then get the id of the slider like this:

```
public function createSlider(Request $request)
{
    $input = Request::all();

    // Create slider
    $slider = Sliders::create($input);

    if (Input::hasFile('image')) {

        // Use the slider id
        $imageName = $slider->id . '.' .
            $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $request->file('image')->move(
            base_path() . '/public/assets/image/', $imageName
        );

        $input->image = $imageName;

    }
    return redirect('/admin');
}
```